# Jquery Fancybox fails to show image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox

I don't know why it fails but when you click a link that is an image, fancybox fails showing a message like, "The requested content cannot be loaded...". I've checked the href( is set dynamically) and its the correct path. I initialized the fancybox like so $("a.fancybox").fancybox(), which is basically all links that is of type fancybox. It use to work but for some reason it doesn't work anymore. Relative nor direct path works. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the `fancybox()` plugin uses the class `fancybox` - what might be happening is that you are conflicting that class name. try naming the class `a_fancybox` and see if things change.

Comment: actually problem is solved. This is an adobe air application and for some reason, I needed to append, "file:///" before the path for it to work. Thanks again.